# Spam-Mail always in inbox and not in ".Spam"-directory (Postfix+Dovecot+SpamAssasian+ClamAV)

Tags: 14.04, email, postfix, dovecot

As the title already says I receive Spam mails always in my mail inbox and not redirected to the Postfix Spam directory ".Spam" for each mail user. Any ideas why? (Ubuntu 14.04.1 with Postfix+Dovecot+SpamAssasian+ClamAV)

My configuration is as follows:

/etc/amavis/conf.d/20-debian_defaults

```
$QUARANTINEDIR = "$MYHOME/virusmails";
```

/etc/amavis/conf.d/20-debian_defaults

```
@whitelist_sender_acl = qw( .$mydomain );
$final_virus_destiny      = D_DISCARD; # (defaults to D_BOUNCE)
$final_banned_destiny     = D_DISCARD;  # (defaults to D_BOUNCE)
$final_spam_destiny       = D_PASS;  # D_DISCARD (defaults to D_REJECT)
$final_bad_header_destiny = D_PASS;  # (defaults to D_PASS), D_BOUNCE suggested
```

/var/log/mail.log

```
    Jan  2 01:11:47 h2376680 dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<user1@example.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=::1, lip=::1, mpid=29949, TLS, session=<LwXFL6ALuQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
Jan  2 01:11:47 h2376680 dovecot: imap(user1@example.com): Disconnected: Logged out in=59 out=477
Jan  2 01:11:50 h2376680 postfix/smtpd[29951]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan  2 01:11:50 h2376680 postfix/smtpd[29951]: 78A6D36502180: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan  2 01:11:50 h2376680 postfix/cleanup[29943]: 78A6D36502180: message-id=<aabe57b2c0c035eb78bc63cebfb7d5ba@webmail.example.com>
Jan  2 01:11:50 h2376680 postfix/qmgr[26016]: 78A6D36502180: from=<user1@example.com>, size=2115, nrcpt=1 (queue active)

Jan  2 01:11:50 h2376680 amavis[29933]: (29933-01) Passed SPAM {RelayedTaggedInternal,Quarantined}, LOCAL [::1]:54297 [::1] <user1@example.com> -> <user1@example.com>, quarantine: Z/spam-ZbwHIOZCG3mB.gz, Queue-ID: 2CFFD36501BFF, Message-ID: <aabe57b2c0c035eb78bc63cebfb7d5ba@webmail.example.com>, mail_id: ZbwHIOZCG3mB, Hits: 999.002, size: 1265, queued_as: 78A6D36502180, 3183 ms

Jan  2 01:11:50 h2376680 postfix/smtp[29945]: 2CFFD36501BFF: to=<user1@example.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=3.3, delays=0.06/0.1/0.01/3.2, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 78A6D36502180)
Jan  2 01:11:50 h2376680 postfix/qmgr[26016]: 2CFFD36501BFF: removed
Jan  2 01:11:50 h2376680 dovecot: lmtp(29953): Connect from local
Jan  2 01:11:50 h2376680 dovecot: lmtp(29953, user1@example.com): rfsRIEbipVQBdQAA6SEkQA: msgid=<aabe57b2c0c035eb78bc63cebfb7d5ba@webmail.example.com>: saved mail to INBOX
Jan  2 01:11:50 h2376680 postfix/lmtp[29952]: 78A6D36502180: to=<user1@example.com>, relay=example.com[private/dovecot-lmtp], delay=0.07, delays=0.01/0.02/0.01/0.03, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 <user1@example.com> rfsRIEbipVQBdQAA6SEkQA Saved)
Jan  2 01:11:50 h2376680 dovecot: lmtp(29953): Disconnect from local: Successful quit
Jan  2 01:11:50 h2376680 postfix/qmgr[26016]: 78A6D36502180: removed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The solution that works for my Ubuntu 14.04 system, thanks to you guys:**

```
sudo apt-get install dovecot-sieve

sudo nano /etc/dovecot/conf.d/20-lmtp.conf

protocol lmtp {
    mail_plugins = $mail_plugins sieve
}

sudo nano /etc/dovecot/conf.d/90-sieve.conf

plugin {
    sieve_before = /var/mail/sieve/spam-global.sieve
    sieve_dir = /var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n/sieve/scripts/
    sieve = /var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n/sieve/active-script.sieve
}

cd /var/mail
mkdir sieve
cd sieve
touch spam-global.sieve
chown -R vmail:mail /var/mail/sieve/

sudo nano /var/mail/sieve/spam-global.sieve

    require "fileinto";
    if header :contains "X-Spam-Flag" "YES" {
      fileinto "Spam";
    }

service dovecot restart
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not told it to do so.

You have to move spam classified mails server-side or tell the clients to move it.

In combination with Dovecot, I do guess the common way is utilizing [sieve plugin](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Pigeonhole/Sieve/Examples).

Comment: I have already installed amavis-new. How can I configure it to forward classified mails to the Spam-Dir of each user here, please?

Comment: amavis-new has nothing to do with the actual mail deliver. that is done with dovecot.

Comment: use sieve; `sudo apt-get install dovecot-sieve`